# Nginx as a Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy and have configuration as follows

```
upstream ba{
   server 127.0.0.1:8091;
   server 127.0.0.1:8092;    
}

server {
   listen 8098;
   server_name 127.0.0.1:8098;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://ba;
   }
}
```

My Question is if Client A is routed to 8091 and Client B is routed to 8092, then will nginx handle all subsequent calls of client A to 8091 and client B to 8092? I know for sure that if I use ip_hash then it sure does, but how does nginx behave in this case.

Thanks
--SD

Comment: No, it'll handle all requests as usual. odd requests will be served on  port 8091 , and even requests on 8092.

Comment: is there a way to achieve loadbalancing with ip hashing, I would like all the clients connect to 8091 be connected to 8091 for all subsequent requests (ip_hash option of nginx) and equally load 8091 and 8092 servers with the number of clients (round robin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls. look at the "sticky" module

Comment: I used this as well, and the cookie gets lost when my application jumps from auth page to home page.